# Unable to create new user in WordPress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

> I am working on a WordPress Multisite, and while creating a new user
>   or existing user in the WordPress backend **(either on the main site or
>   the sub site)**, it's showing me an error message saying "**The requested
>   user does not exist**".
>
> Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: please consider asking at wordpress.stackexchange.com instead

Answer (score 1):

The add user form can be slightly confusing on WordPress Multisite at first - I made the same mistake.

The top form you've highlighted there is for adding an *existing* user from the Multisite network to the current site. eg. if your user is already on another site in the network, this form can be used to give them access to the current site as well.

If you want to add a **brand new user** to the Multisite network *and* to the current site in one go, you want to use the form directly below this - the Add New User form.

Comment: i have a user and already on another site but when i trying to add that user in new site as existing user same error occur, and also  new user can't create.

Comment: Hmm that is strange. Have you tried it from the Multisite admin as well?

Comment: yes i have tried in Multisite and user added but whenever i trying to add that user in sub site as a existing user given me same error.

Comment: It sounds like there could be something wrong with your database. Can you delete the user from the Multisite user management and try re-adding them again?

Comment: still same error showing. i have removed it from database and trying to add but still not doing.

Comment: Hmm.. is this a brand new site or an existing site? Something's wrong somewhere... so if it's a brand new site I might consider setting it up again. Or perhaps double check that every file that should be present is present (i.e. compare with the files from the latest Wordpress version)

Comment: How did you go with this @sameersheikh?